# SQL, Select in Looping returning repeated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have been working on a project for a very long time and I can't seem to find out how to do it. I have a looping code and a function combined but can't seem to get the output I wanted to see.

My code is like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 as Day
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Day+1 FROM CTE
    WHERE Day < 15
), Name as (Select * from fn_logs(@Month, @Year,@date_from,@date_to)

)

SELECT CTE.Day, 
CASE WHEN Name.DAtee != CTE.Day THEN Name.Fullname ELSE Name.Fullname END as Fullname,  
CASE WHEN Name.DAtee != CTE.Day THEN ' ' ELSE Name.AMIN END as AMIN, 
CASE WHEN Name.DAtee != CTE.Day THEN ' ' ELSE Name.AMOUT END as AMOUT, 
CASE WHEN Name.DAtee != CTE.Day THEN ' ' ELSE Name.PMIN END as PMIN, 
CASE WHEN Name.DAtee != CTE.Day THEN ' ' ELSE Name.PMOUT END as PMOUT
FROM CTE, Name

group by CTE.Day,Name.Fullname,Name.AMIN,Name.AMOUT,Name.PMIN,Name.PMOUT
```

where the **Name.DAtee** gets the day of the date
The output I wanted to happen was like:

```
Day  Fullname  AM-IN  AM-OUT  PM-IN  PM-OUT
1    Ara Ast   8:00   12:00   12:03  5:00
2    Ara Ast   7:51   12:22   12:23  5:10
3    Ara Ast      
1    Clara Est 8:01   12:12   12:25  5:07
2    Clara Est 
3    Clara Est 7:41   12:02   12:15  5:00
```

I wanted to show all the days a single employees has logged and when no date was logged, it will automatically show no value. The output I get was like:

```
Day  Fullname  AM-IN  AM-OUT  PM-IN  PM-OUT
1    Ara Ast   8:00   12:00   12:03  5:00
2    Ara Ast   
3    Ara Ast 
1    Ara Ast   
2    Ara Ast   7:51   12:22   12:23  5:10
3    Ara Ast 
1    Ara Ast   
2    Ara Ast   
3    Ara Ast
```

**Sample Data**

```
INSERT INTO table1 (Fullname, Date, AMIN, AMOUT, PMIN, PMOUT) VALUES 
('Ara Ast', '2/1/2018','8:00 AM','12:00 PM','1:00 PM','5:00 PM'), 
('Ema Watson', '2/1/2018','8:00 AM','12:00 PM','1:00 PM','5:00 PM'), 
('Ema Watson', '2/2/2018','8:00 AM','12:00 PM','1:00 PM','5:00 PM'), 
('Ara Ast', '2/3/2018','8:00 AM','12:00 PM','1:00 PM','5:00 PM');
```

The values seem to repeat and whenever the value was not equal to the date, it prints the no value. Sorry I am kinda still in the learning stage of the sql server coding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your database version? db2,mssql,mysql?

Comment: @D-Shih I am currently using SSMS 2016

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output from them

Comment: @uzi INSERT INTO table1 (Fullname, Date, AMIN, AMOUT, PMIN, PMOUT)
VALUES
    ('Ara Ast', '2/1/2018','8:00 AM','12:00 PM','1:00 PM','5:00 PM'),
    ('Ema Watson', '2/1/2018','8:00 AM','12:00 PM','1:00 PM','5:00 PM'),
    ('Ema Watson', '2/2/2018','8:00 AM','12:00 PM','1:00 PM','5:00 PM'),
    ('Ara Ast', '2/3/2018','8:00 AM','12:00 PM','1:00 PM','5:00 PM');  --for some sample data. The output I wanted to happen is included above. The same pattern as above.

Comment: In your sample data day is `date` while it's `int` in the question. How do you identify first day?

Comment: @uzi There is a loop getting the fifteen number then each will be identified by using a case statement where if the day matches the loop in the digit, it will populate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this query. According to your comment that's what you need

```
declare @t table (Fullname varchar(100), Date date, AMIN varchar(100), AMOUT varchar(100), PMIN varchar(100), PMOUT varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @t (Fullname, Date, AMIN, AMOUT, PMIN, PMOUT) 
VALUES ('Ara Ast', '20180201','8:00 AM','12:00 PM','1:00 PM','5:00 PM')
    , ('Ema Watson', '20180201','8:00 AM','12:00 PM','1:00 PM','5:00 PM')
    , ('Ema Watson', '20180202','8:00 AM','12:00 PM','1:00 PM','5:00 PM')
    , ('Ara Ast', '20180203','8:00 AM','12:00 PM','1:00 PM','5:00 PM');

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 as Day
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Day+1 FROM CTE
    WHERE Day < 15
)
select 
    * 
from 
    cte c
    cross join (select distinct Fullname from @t) t
    left join @t tt on t.Fullname = tt.Fullname and c.Day = day(tt.Date)
order by 2,1
```

Comment: Whoa! It worked perfectly but how did the joins do the trick? Sorry I'm getting confused with its procedure.

Comment: @JohnClarenceCastro, main part is `cross join`. It forms all combinations of each person with all days